# Migration for Sequence not working on ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using these packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.1" />
```

My code:

```
// generate id 
modelBuilder.HasSequence("UNIQUEIdGenerator", schema: "public")
        .StartsAt(2000000000)
        .IncrementsBy(1);

// TestId is not primary key
modelBuilder.Entity<ModelTest>()
        .Property(d => d.TestId)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CONCAT('PREFIX', NEXTVAL('\"UNIQUEIdGenerator\"'))");
```

When I do migration it get success without any error, but when I open **PGADMIN** and navigate to the database and check the sequence under public schema, it doesn't show me an UNIQUEIdGenerator sequence.

**Note:- Table ModelTest was already there, when i did migration for this sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution ("Work Around"). If I delete all migration files and regenerate all the migrations file and then update the db it work fine.

Step 1:- delete all the migration file + snapshot file

Step 2:- generate migration files dotnet ef migrations add

Step 3:- dotnet ef migrations script

Now if you search the output it will show you "Create Sequence" sql command, which was missing when i was trying to do with previously.